# Struggling with integration in a Differential Equations problem

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

This is part of a hw problem for school. (the original problem is the DE $x' = x^2 -4$)
It is a differential equations course but I'm stuck on a calculus part. 
I plugged the integral to wolfram alpha and can't follow why the
    integral of $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{1-u^2} du = \dfrac{1}{2} \left(\log(u+1)-\log(1-u)\right)+ C$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{1}{1-u^2}=\dfrac{A}{1-u}+\dfrac{B}{1+u}$, for some $A,B\in \Bbb R$. Find $A$ and $B$.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368665/derivation-of-the-general-forms-of-partial-fractions) might be helpful.