# Integration $\int\left(\frac1{(x-1)^2(x+1)^3}\right)dx$

Tags: integration

everyone.

I am having problems to solve this integral:

$$\int\left(\frac1{(x-1)^2*(x+1)^3}\right)dx$$

Any hints will be appreciated

Comment: Do you know about partial fractions?

Comment: Generally, $*$ is multiplication for computer languages, but not for mathematicians.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it as
$$
\frac{1}{(x-1)^2 (x+1)^3} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{C}{x+1} + \frac{D}{(x+1)^2} + \frac{E}{(x+1)^3}$$
where $A,B,C,D,E$ are constants

Added as afterthought

For your reference
$$ A=-{{3}\over{16}} , B={{1}\over{8}} , C={{3}\over{16}} , D=
 {{1}\over{4}} , E={{1}\over{4}} $$

Comment: Thank you. I got another question now. When should i use $A*x+B$ and $A$ in numerator?

Comment: @aisas See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368665/derivation-of-the-general-forms-of-partial-fractions).

Comment: @aisas Yes, that will help with the integration too! I find it generally easy to keep the numerators as constants and avoid too many $\log$ identities in the final answer.