# Why do repeated linear factors have to be dealt with in this way?

Tags: intuition, partial-fractions

When dealing with partial fractions, and your denominator has a repeated linear factor, the way to solve is this:

$\frac{2x+3}{(x-2)^2}=\frac{A}{(x-2)^2}+\frac{B}{(x-2)}$

$2x+3=A+B(x-2)$

and so on.

Now, even though I know the following method doesn't work, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

$\frac{2x+3}{(x-2)^2}=\frac{A}{(x-2)}+\frac{B}{(x-2)}$

$2x+3=A(x-2)+B(x-2)$

Why can't I treat repeated linear factors like other linear factors?  I'm sure the answer is very obvious, but I can't see it right now.  I mean, I can see that I can't set $x=2$ here.  But yeah.  I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: you say yourself that you know it doesn't work, and then you ask why you can't do that? Well, you can't do it because it does not work.

Comment: Because $\frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{B}{x-2}=\frac{A+B}{x-2}$. Is that really possible?

Comment: In particular, can you solve: $2x+3=(A+B)(x-2)$? Is $2x+3$ a multiple of $x-2$?

Comment: @IttayWeiss The question is, why doesn't it work.

Comment: is it a philosophical question? like why is $2+3\ne 4$?

Comment: @KorganRivera didn't say what?

Comment: [Reference question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368665/derivation-of-the-general-forms-of-partial-fractions) for partial fractions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You answered my question.  I must have messed up the arithmetic to not have seen that before.  Thanks.