# Proof of a theorem about polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have known a theorem from the link [Derivation of the general forms of partial fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368665/derivation-of-the-general-forms-of-partial-fractions)

The theorem is that
a polynomial of odd degree has a root.But I don't know its proof.Can anyone prove it with intuition.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the polynomial $P$ is monic, for this is irrelevant as the existence of a zero. Also, I presume, it's over the reals, for else this is just not true.

Then $\lim_{x\to-\infty}P(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}P(x)=\infty$ because the polynomial is dominated by its leading term, which is an odd function -- it's $x^{2n+1}$. Since $P$ is a continuous function with both a positive and negative value, it must have a zero. Pictorially, if it has a value above and below the $x$-axis and the graph is continuous, then it has to cross the $x$-axis.

I am not entirely sure why you refer to partial fractions.

Comment: I mentioned partial fractions because I'm trying to learn the derivation of the methods of fraction decomposition.And the above theorem is required for this purpose.